# Criptografar uma String para RC2 em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, criptografia

Há uma forma de usar criptografia RC2 através de alguma função JavaScript?

Estou fazendo uma aplicação mobile onde o token de validação dela precisa ser através dessa criptografia pois todo o resto do sistema já a utiliza.

**EDITADO**

Através de um comentário abaixo (feito pelo @Omni), encontrei a biblioteca CryptoJS onde ela encripta para RC2. o Problema é que o resultado que ela me retorna não consigo tratar a mesma para uma string binária. Tenho os seguintes valores:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/tomyun/crypto-js/xeit-3.1.2/build/rollups/rc2.js"></script>
<script>
    var VALUE = "29udbAj%(y4";
    var KEY = "M^$UCLThSEZGnet";
    var KEYSIZE= 64;

    var e = CryptoJS.RC2.encrypt(VALUE,KEY,{effectiveKeyBits: KEYSIZE});
    var d = CryptoJS.RC2.decrypt(e,KEY, {effectiveKeyBits: KEYSIZE});
    /*
        preciso retornar o resultado = '95817E9B4F230CD37EB564BD13BB568F'
    */
</script>
```

como faço pra chegar até o resultado acima?

Comment: Que tal usar [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/tomyun/crypto-js)?

Comment: estou estudando esta a CryptoJS, mas não estou conseguindo o resultado que procuro...

Comment: Convém então colocar na sua pergunta o que já tentou, o que já utilizou e que dificuldades encontrou para o conseguirmos ajuda e não dar sugestões repetidas (por exemplo, qual o seu problema com o CryptoJS?)

Comment: @Omni coloquei os dados que preciso retornar, na edição da pergunta. poderia me auxiliar por favor?

Comment: Pelo que estou a perceber o seu problema deixou de ser a criptografia mas sim o converter o texto encriptado para hexadecimal?

Comment: provavelmente sim, nunca trabalhei com criptografia antes, o setor que está fazendo meu webservice precisa que eu envie uma variável com o valor do resultado para que ele possa validar minhas requisições AJAX. e a variável Value é a chave de cada aplicativo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23284/discussion-between-omni-and-leandroluk).